# Windows server virtual machine in a linux server ONLY with terminal. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, terminal, vmware-server

I have a linux server that I use for various services since a very long time. I would like to run some new software on it but it's a windows software that is a server of some kind. Unfortunately emulators didn't help do the job correctly.

I use my linux server through the terminal only. I never use displays. Is it possible to use something like VMWare VSphere with Windows Server 2012 without requiring display?

Please tell me about your experience in that. I never used Windows Server before (but I'm pretty familiar with desktop versions of windows, which never look to be manageable only with terminals).

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: If you put a -1, explain why you don't like the question. I can improve it. I suspect the guy throwing me that -1 is just a linux fan hating the idea ^_^

Comment: So your question is: _does it exist any virtual machine system that is possible to install without X or graphic environment, and on which is possible to run in text only mode Windows Server_? BTW what do you refer with [windows server 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server)?

Comment: @Hastur Yes, that's exactly my question. Excuse my ignorance, but I have never, ever used Windows servers before, and never witnessed any windows system using terminals. That's why I'm asking. I meant Windows Server 2012 (or any other version for that matter), sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you go fully stripped down, you're probably still going to need some sort of GUI for interacting, even if it's just the [Minimal Server Interface](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2012/05/09/configuring-the-minimal-server-interface.aspx) and you're running everything command-line from there. At the very least, you'll likely need some form of GUI access for initial setup tasks.

There may be some hope for working with [Emergency Management Services redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/554298/windows-serial-console) and Server Core/Hyper-V (various resources available, but it's a small niche, try [Veeam's article](http://www.veeam.com/blog/rdp-rsat-free-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-remote-desktop-appliance-linux.html) for some possibly interesting links to start from, along with the [Microsoft Hyper-V download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2).

And a couple days after this went up originally, Microsoft announced [Nano Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2015/04/08/microsoft-announces-nano-server-for-modern-apps-and-cloud.aspx) (more [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/08/microsoft-unveils-new-container-technologies-for-the-next-generation-cloud)) stripped down for by removing the GUI stack, Win32, and other components. "There is no local logon or Remote Desktop support. All management is performed remotely via WMI and PowerShell."

Comment: If you're not updated on edits, re-read the answer - MS announced today "Nano" server, managed via WMI and PowerShell only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very good news. Finally something rational about Windows Servers.